# phpmyadmin blank screen after installing Zend server

Tags: zend-framework, phpmyadmin

I installed LAMP on Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTE. Then I installed phpmyadmin. Everything was good. I used phpadmin to do lots of DB administration....

Then I installed Zend CE server. Now, phpmyadmin throws a blank page. No login screen.

So, I reinstalled my VPS in the same sequence again. No luck. Same behavior.

This time, I installed Apache, Mysql, PHP and Zend server in that order. Then I installed phpmyadmin....Unfortunately, still blank page on phpmyadmin.

Any help?...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the server error log, most likely you are missing some required extension.  The blank page means its running into a fatal PHP error.  You can enable error_reporting and display_errors in php.ini to see the error on screen as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, for all those that posted their suggestions to my above issue, thanks!.

Of course, I had to dig deeper into forums and threads to find the specific root cause and solution for this issue.....and after spending few hours...finally, I resolved it!. Thanks to the following bug discussion link on php.net.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25876

I tired many suggested fixes there but they didn't help. The suggestion that finally fixed the problem was pasted below ( so that let the credit go to the right owner):

---

[2011-03-03 12:18 UTC] comments at htmlcompressor dot com
If you are gettin the following error:
"Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: files (path: ) in...."
Make sure that you have setup the session save path in your php.ini:
session.save_path = "/tmp"
which seems to be disabled by default.

---

I swear using Open Source software is tough!. I have spent whole day on this issue alone. My goal was to build some software and I have yet to get to it!!.